# zsh: access last command line argument given to a script

Tags: zsh

I want to get the last element of `$*`.  The best I've found so far is:

```
 last=`eval "echo \\\$$#"`
```

But that seems overly opaque.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In zsh, you can either use the `P` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) or treat `@` as an array containing the positional parameters:

```
last=${(P)#}
last=${@[$#]}
```

A way that works in all Bourne-style shells including zsh is

```
eval last=\$$#
```

(You were on the right track, but running `echo` just to get its output is pointless.)

Answer (score 9):

```
last=${@[-1]}
```

should do the trick. More generally,

```
${@[n]}
```

will yield the *n*th parameter, while

```
${@[-n]}
```

will yield the *n*th to last parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The colon parameter expansion is not in POSIX, but this works in at least zsh, bash, and ksh:

```
${@:$#}
```

When there are no arguments, `${@:$#}` is treated as `$0` in zsh and ksh but as empty in bash:

```
$ zsh -c 'echo ${@:$#}'
zsh
$ ksh -c 'echo ${@:$#}'
ksh
$ bash -c 'echo ${@:$#}'

$
```